# plsql dynamic content region hyperlink not working

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex-18.2

I am working on plsql dynamic content to generate some html base controls like `<ul>` and `<li>` I am facing issue on `<li>` while implementing hyperlink on list item . Problem is that once i run the code it generates all list but hyperlink works only for first list item and i want to send parameters to modal dialogue which is being opened on `<li>` hyperlink.

Here is my code how i generating the list items

```
FOR i IN WEEK LOOP
  htp.p('<h3>'||i.WEEK_NAME||'</h3>'); 
  FOR j IN DAYS (i.WEEK_ID) LOOP    
    htp.p('<div class="div">');
    htp.p('<h3>'||j.WEEK_DAY||'</h3>');
    htp.p('<ul class=menu>');
    htp.p('<br>');
    FOR k IN MEALS (j.DAY_ID,i.WEEK_ID)  LOOP   

            htp.p('<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>'||k.MEAL_NAME||'</span>
                        </li>');

    END LOOP;
    htp.p('</ul>');
    htp.p('</div>');
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;

    htp.p('</body>');
    htp.p('</html>');
```

Please suggest what exactly i am doing wrong with hyper link that hyperlink only enables for very first list item

**Update**

```
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 1</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 2</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 3</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 1</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 2</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 3</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 1</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 2</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 3</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 1</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 2</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 3</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 1</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 2</span>
                        </li>
<li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" id = "modal" value="abc"></i>
                            </a>
                            <span>Meal 3</span>
                        </li>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: I have inserted in table after `htp.p(<li>....)` tag table show all values same as first but on web page link works only for very first list item not for rest of values

Comment: I repeat, please show the generate HTML to make it easier to help.

Comment: PLease check the update i have put the table inside the loop and this is what i posted from table

Comment: I was able to run the generated code and generate all of the hyper links in google chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am Using Chrome